# O que fazer para o serviço não ser finalizado pelo Android?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Tenho um service que roda em segundo plano para pegar a localização e ir gravando em um texto.
O service é iniciado junto com o android através do BroadcastReceiver.
Funciona perfeitamente, mas após umas 12h do service rodando, o android finaliza e tenho que reiniciar o aparelho para ele voltar a executar.

Class BootReceiver:

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent myService = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
    context.startService(myService);
}
```

Meu service:

```
public class LocationService extends Service {


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

public void localizacao() {

    Log.i("GPS", "Iniciou");

    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i("GPS", "Serviço executando");

                       // PEGA LOCALIZAÇÃO E GRAVA
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Intent myService = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    startService(myService);
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Intent myService = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    startService(myService);
}}
```

Manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".LocationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:singleUser="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />

    <receiver android:name=".BootReciever">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para que o android não finalize meu service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Tente fazer desta forma.

**Adicione a onStartCommand ao seu Service:**

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
 
    }
```

**Dentro desse método defina a flag que será retornada:**

```
    return (super.onStartCommand(intent, START_REDELIVER_INTENT, startId));
```

Desta maneira, se o android finalizar o service seu service será reiniciado automaticamente.

> START_REDELIVER_INTENT
>
> Se o sistema eliminar o serviço após o retorno de onStartCommand(),
> recrie o serviço e chame onStartCommand() com a última intenção que
> foi entregue ao serviço. Quaisquer intenções pendentes são entregues,
> por sua vez. Isto é adequado para serviços que estejam realizando um
> trabalho ativamente que deva ser retomado imediatamente, como o
> download de um arquivo.

OBS: Voce tem que startar o seu envio de localização dentro do metodo onStartCommand.

Existem outros tipos de flags para serem utilizadas como START_NOT_STICKY, START_STICKY, START_REDELIVER_INTENT.

Veja mais em: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Tentei fazer isso mas não funcionou, depois de 12h o android finalizou o service. Tenho um app que fica rodando eternamente teria como eu chamar o service de um apk através de outro apk? ai resolveria meu problema

Comment: @LuizLanza pelos meus conhecimentos em android, é impossível você manter um service rodando o tempo todo, quando o android precisar de memoria ou tiver outra prioridade ele pode matar seu service. Mas você pode tratar sua reinicialização que acontece de forma instantânea quando você cria o service da forma que eu te passei.